# I'm getting an unknown error in my c++ project? Cant figure out whats wrong

Tags: c++, c++11, calculator

My goal is to make a **calculator** in **c++**. I'm using **Visual Studio Code**. The **calculator** will include calculation order (First parantheses, then * and /, then + and -). In the terminal you write an **equation**, for example: **3 * (4 - 1)**. How the program works is that I have a **vector** containing the equation as type string. Then I have **2d vector** containing both the equation as numbers (double) and the **'layer'** of the number. The **layer** is something I use to determine the calculation order of each number, determined by the number of open/closed parantheses prior. I have not gotten to the calculation of the numbers yet, but there is an **issue** I'm facing of which I have no clue how to fix.

The problem is, whenever I write something in the terminal, specifically when I enter a space, the code stops after **return 0;** **at main()**. Afterwards a new file opens up in my tab named **'new_allocater.h'**. Additionally there appears no error message at all, the code stops inside **'new_allocater.h'** as if there was a breakpoint.

So far it doesnt seem like the problem is actually hindering my code from running, because the problem appears after **return 0;** at **main()**. But its definitely going to come back to bite me in the future.

**Here's the code for my calculator project:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string s, const char f) { // s = string, f = delimiter
    // Function for turning strings into vectors using a delimiter

    vector<string> v; // List of substrings to be returned
    int startPoint = 0; // Startpos of substring
    const int stringLength = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == f) {
            s.erase(i, 1); // Remove delimiter character from the string
            v.push_back(s.substr(startPoint, i-startPoint));
            startPoint = i;
        }
    }
    v.push_back(s.substr(startPoint, s.back()));
    
    return v;
}

bool isDigit(const string &s) {
    // Return true or false value whether a string is a digit or not
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789.") == string::npos;
}

double convertMainToAlt(string s) {
    const int stringLength = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == ')' || s[i] == 'V') {
            s.erase(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    if (isDigit(s)) {
        return stod(s);
    }

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Main variables / vectors / arrays used for the program

    string mainEquation; // String of equation
    vector<string> mainEquationList; // {"(5", "+", "10)", "-", "4.2"}

    getline(cin, mainEquation); // Get user input for the equation
    mainEquationList = split(mainEquation, ' ');

    vector<vector<double>> altEquationList = {{0}, {0}}; /*
    {{equation numbers}, {layer numbers}}*/

    for (int i = 0; i < mainEquationList.size(); i++)
    {
        altEquationList[0][i] = convertMainToAlt(mainEquationList[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mainEquationList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << altEquationList[0][i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "===========================" << endl;
    
    // Layer Number
    /*
    Assign layer number to each element by counting the number of open/closed parantheses before.
    +1 to layer number for every open parantheses that appears before or is on the same element.
    -1 to layer number for every closed paranhteses that appears before the element.*/

    int layerIncOrDec = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mainEquationList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (mainEquationList[i].find("(") != string::npos) {
            layerIncOrDec++;
            altEquationList[1][i] = layerIncOrDec;
        } else if (mainEquationList[i].find(")") != string::npos) {
            altEquationList[1][i] = layerIncOrDec;
            layerIncOrDec--;
        } else {
            altEquationList[1][i] = layerIncOrDec;
        }
    }

    int highestLayer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mainEquationList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (altEquationList[1][i] > highestLayer) {
            highestLayer = altEquationList[1][i];
        }
    }

    // Print information

    for (int i = 0; i < mainEquationList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << altEquationList[0][i] << " - " << altEquationList[1][i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Here's the code for the 'new_allocater.h' file:**
The error occurs at line 168:

```
// Allocator that wraps operator new -*- C++ -*-

// Copyright (C) 2001-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file bits/new_allocator.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{memory}
 */

#ifndef _STD_NEW_ALLOCATOR_H
#define _STD_NEW_ALLOCATOR_H 1

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <new>
#include <bits/functexcept.h>
#include <bits/move.h>
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <type_traits>
#endif

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  /**
   * @brief  An allocator that uses global `new`, as per C++03 [20.4.1].
   * @ingroup allocators
   *
   * This is precisely the allocator defined in the C++ Standard.
   *   - all allocation calls `operator new`
   *   - all deallocation calls `operator delete`
   *
   * This is the default base-class implementation of `std::allocator`,
   * and is also the base-class of the `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator` extension.
   * You should use either `std::allocator` or `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator`
   * instead of using this directly.
   *
   * @tparam  _Tp  Type of allocated object.
   *
   * @headerfile memory
   */
  template<typename _Tp>
    class __new_allocator
    {
    public:
      typedef _Tp        value_type;
      typedef std::size_t     size_type;
      typedef std::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;
#if __cplusplus <= 201703L
      typedef _Tp*       pointer;
      typedef const _Tp* const_pointer;
      typedef _Tp&       reference;
      typedef const _Tp& const_reference;

      template<typename _Tp1>
    struct rebind
    { typedef __new_allocator<_Tp1> other; };
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 2103. propagate_on_container_move_assignment
      typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
#endif

      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
      __new_allocator() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }

      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
      __new_allocator(const __new_allocator&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }

      template<typename _Tp1>
    __attribute__((__always_inline__))
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    __new_allocator(const __new_allocator<_Tp1>&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }

#if __cplusplus <= 201703L
      ~__new_allocator() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }

      pointer
      address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return std::__addressof(__x); }

      const_pointer
      address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return std::__addressof(__x); }
#endif

#if __has_builtin(__builtin_operator_new) >= 201802L
# define _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW __builtin_operator_new
# define _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE __builtin_operator_delete
#else
# define _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW ::operator new
# define _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE ::operator delete
#endif

      // NB: __n is permitted to be 0.  The C++ standard says nothing
      // about what the return value is when __n == 0.
      _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD _Tp*
      allocate(size_type __n, const void* = static_cast<const void*>(0))
      {
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
    // 3308. std::allocator<void>().allocate(n)
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) != 0, "cannot allocate incomplete types");
#endif

    if (__builtin_expect(__n > this->_M_max_size(), false))
      {
        // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
        // 3190. allocator::allocate sometimes returns too little storage
        if (__n > (std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(_Tp)))
          std::__throw_bad_array_new_length();
        std::__throw_bad_alloc();
      }

#if __cpp_aligned_new
    if (alignof(_Tp) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
      {
        std::align_val_t __al = std::align_val_t(alignof(_Tp));
        return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp),
                               __al));
      }
#endif
    return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
      }

      // __p is not permitted to be a null pointer.
      void
      deallocate(_Tp* __p, size_type __n __attribute__ ((__unused__)))
      {
#if __cpp_sized_deallocation
# define _GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(p, n) (p), (n) * sizeof(_Tp)
#else
# define _GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(p, n) (p)
#endif

#if __cpp_aligned_new
    if (alignof(_Tp) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
      {
        _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n),
                     std::align_val_t(alignof(_Tp)));
        return;
      }
#endif
    _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n)); // Line 168, the error occurs here
      }

#undef _GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC
#undef _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE
#undef _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW

#if __cplusplus <= 201703L
      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      size_type
      max_size() const _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      { return _M_max_size(); }

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      template<typename _Up, typename... _Args>
    __attribute__((__always_inline__))
    void
    construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<_Up, _Args...>::value)
    { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

      template<typename _Up>
    __attribute__((__always_inline__))
    void
    destroy(_Up* __p)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<_Up>::value)
    { __p->~_Up(); }
#else
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 402. wrong new expression in [some_] allocator::construct
      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      void
      construct(pointer __p, const _Tp& __val)
      { ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(__val); }

      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      void
      destroy(pointer __p) { __p->~_Tp(); }
#endif
#endif // ! C++20

      template<typename _Up>
    friend __attribute__((__always_inline__)) _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR bool
    operator==(const __new_allocator&, const __new_allocator<_Up>&)
    _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
    { return true; }

#if __cpp_impl_three_way_comparison < 201907L
      template<typename _Up>
    friend __attribute__((__always_inline__)) _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR bool
    operator!=(const __new_allocator&, const __new_allocator<_Up>&)
    _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
    { return false; }
#endif

    private:
      __attribute__((__always_inline__))
      _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR size_type
      _M_max_size() const _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      {
#if __PTRDIFF_MAX__ < __SIZE_MAX__
    return std::size_t(__PTRDIFF_MAX__) / sizeof(_Tp);
#else
    return std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(_Tp);
#endif
      }
    };

_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
} // namespace

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: You should go into the debugger view and inspect the stack trace

Comment: Looks like heap corruption to me. Use your debugger to find out where the problem is.

Comment: There's something being wronly de-allocated... It's very hard for us to spot it with so much coe in your question. as the project is not so big, you could try an old "debugging" tecnique, where you comment all the code , except the first lines, you check no error and you add back your code one by one :D  ... or use a good debugger

Comment: You're accessing `altEquationList` out of bounds. https://godbolt.org/z/eTsas7nhd Use `.at(index)` instead of `[index]` and it will throw an exception when this happens rather than silently corrupt memory for you to discover later. Tools like AddressSanitizer can help you find these issues too.

Comment: OT: Don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Please do not post errors messages as images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Note when crash happens during debugging find window named "call stack" and find your code there (first from top of the list).

Comment: `3 * (4 - 1)` -- FYI -- There's *tons* of material on how to properly do this in a *formal* manner, not with ad-hoc stuff that your code is doing.  *Shunting-yard* is one such method.  Another is to create an abstract-syntax-tree.  How will you eventually compute `(3 * (4 - 1) + 7)` or something more complex?  Just to warn you -- if you find out that your code, even if you fix the crash, does not work for expressions like this, then get prepared to do a massive rewrite to your program just to get it to work again.

Comment: `heap-buffer-overflow` https://godbolt.org/z/h963b7eGE

Comment: Add `#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG 1` at the very beginning of the file (before any `#inlcude`s). Now `std::vector` etc. are using bounds checking and you'll see clearly that you're accessing your vectors out of bounds.

Comment: Also `for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)  {   if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == ')' || s[i] == 'V') {           s.erase(i, 1);...` This looks very very suspicious to me. You should NOT change the string length while iterating over it. Look at std::erase/[std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated based on the comments to make it more clear and comprehensive)

The `altEquationList` is initialized improperly, it's a 2x1 dimension vector, while your `3 * (4 - 1)` example requires 2x5.

Writing this vector with out-of-bounds indices at `altEquationList[0][i] = convertMainToAlt(mainEquationList[i])` causes heap-buffer-overflow.

You might want something like

```cpp
    auto const equationListSize = mainEquationList.size();
    vector<vector<double>> altEquationList = { std::vector<double>(equationListSize), std::vector<double>(equationListSize) };
```

instead of

```cpp
vector<vector<double>> altEquationList = {{0}, {0}};
```

**What do to next time**

- Using `::at()` is safer in the sense that it throws exception upon out-of-bounds indexing. Due to its bound-checking, it's not suggested to use in performance-critical processes as it's slower than `operator[]`. (Actually, it's not suggested in any case, see later)
- What is suggested is using runtime error detection tools for `Debug` mode, like `AddressSanitizer` (Linux, Windows) or `Valgrind` (Linux, extremely slow) or use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for GCC.

If you deploy a tool like these and you have sufficient tests, it's quite safe to get rid of bound-checking operators like `::at()`.

Comment: The problem  is actually accessing the vector with out of bounds indexes which then results in the address sanitizer diagnostic "heap-buffer-overflow"

Comment: The problem is not _accessing the vector with out of bounds index_. The problem is using `operator[]` with out of bounds index. Using `::at()` with the same index would be totally fine and it wouldn't cause heap buffer overflow, but an exception.

Comment: `.at()` is great at finding that stuff, but I hesitate at making it the de-facto recommendation for indexing a vector. It's so slow.

Comment: @sweenish Agreed, it worsen the performance and I should have mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @bbalazs if he'd used `at` it would not be much better, the program would just crash differently because no one catches the exception. But admittedly it would be "clean" crash.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right. A heap/stack overflow is a nasty thing, hard to find without valgrind/asan/etc if the given memory area belongs to the process. Using `at()` would have helped here as it would have showed the exact place of wrongdoing. Anyway, I'm not suggesting to use it, I suggest ASAN or Valgrind, but I've never worked on windows, having no idea what similar tools it has.

Comment: @bbalazs Instead of using `at` you can use `#define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG 1` or compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (gcc), or use a Debug build with the MS compiler, (or maybe something else with other environments/compilers) which will also assert on out of bounds accesses with `operator[]`.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've updated the answer with your comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! I'm still an intermediate programmer and I'm sorry if my question was unconcise and unclear. I will make sure to take your advice into consideration for my future projects.

Comment: @Canyon No worries, no one born with this knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on godbolt it gives a clear indication of what is going wrong. You call std::stod with an invalid value : See https://godbolt.org/z/9MrGjPban

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
```

So really you should run your code again in your debugger and put a breakpoint on your std::stod call and observer what is happening.